# How do I import a soft body bake into another project?

Tags: soft-body

I bake a soft body simulation with 'disk cache' and 'Use Library Path'. When I copy and paste the soft, baked mesh into another project file, or append it into another project file, the bake does not transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.  Turn off disk cache. Turn off Use Library Path.